# Troubles with GO! Aspect-Oriented Framework

Tags: php, aop, goaop

If someone work with GO! framework, can you help me.
I install framework on php 5.3.13. Demo example is working.
But my own example doesn't work.  Aspect(method beforeMethodExecution) is not perfomed.

Here is my code.

Main file:

```
//1 Include kernel and all classes
if (file_exists(__DIR__ .'/../../vendor/autoload.php')) {
     $loader = include __DIR__ .'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
}
// 2 Make own ascpect kernel

use Go\Core\AspectKernel;
use Go\Core\AspectContainer;

class Kernel extends AspectKernel{
  /**
   * Configure an AspectContainer with advisors, aspects and pointcuts
   *
   * @param AspectContainer $container
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function configureAop(AspectContainer $container)
  {
  }
}

//3 Initiate aspect kernel

$Kernel = Kernel::getInstance();

$Kernel->init();

//4 Include aspect
include(__DIR__.'/aspectclass/AspectClass.php');

$aspect = new DebugAspect();

//5 register aspect
$Kernel->getContainer()->registerAspect($aspect);


//6 Include test class

include(__DIR__.'/class/class1.php'); 


//7 Execute test class

$Class = new General('test');
$Class->publicHello();
```

File with test class:

```
class General{
protected $message = '';

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

public function publicHello()
{
    echo 'Hello, you have a public message: ', $this->message, "<br>", PHP_EOL;
}
```

}

File with aspect:

```
use Go\Aop\Aspect;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\FieldAccess;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\FunctionInvocation;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\MethodInvocation;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\After;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Before;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Around;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Pointcut;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\DeclareParents;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\DeclareError;

class DebugAspect implements Aspect{

/**
 * Method that should be called before real method
 *
 * @param MethodInvocation $invocation Invocation
 * @Before("execution(General->*(*))")
 *
 */
public function beforeMethodExecution(MethodInvocation $invocation)
{
    $obj = $invocation->getThis();
    echo 'Calling Before Interceptor for method: ',
    is_object($obj) ? get_class($obj) : $obj,
    $invocation->getMethod()->isStatic() ? '::' : '->',
    $invocation->getMethod()->getName(),
    '()',
    ' with arguments: ',
    json_encode($invocation->getArguments()),
    PHP_EOL;
}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you know, go-aop isn't a PHP extension, so it couldn't transform classes that were loaded directly via `require` or `include`. Internally it tries to overwrite the source code on-the-fly, but it should receive a control (via integration with composer or custom autoloader class).

So, you have an error here:

```
//6 Include test class
include(__DIR__.'/class/class1.php');
```

You explicitly load this class into memory and there is no way to transform it from userland. To pass a control to the framework, you should make this explicitly. Look at the line [AopComposerLoader.php#L99](https://github.com/lisachenko/go-aop-php/blob/master/src/Go/Instrument/ClassLoading/AopComposerLoader.php#L99) to have an idea how it works. Here we include a source file via the [stream source filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php) that pass control to the framework and it can transform the class to weave an aspects.

To fix your example just change an `include` to the following:

```
include (FilterInjectorTransformer::rewrite(__DIR__.'/class/class1.php'));
```

Comment: The question and answer are a bit old, nevertheless AOP is still an actual concept in modern software development.
Thank you lisachenko! I am following your ideas and philosophy since 2015. You inspired me to write my own self-contained, standalone PHP web and CLI framework (it is not ready yet, I have to test it, etc...), it is very simple, but it was a very good experience for me. I did it for fun in my spare time and to increase my knowledge. (max characters length) Continues in the next comment...

Comment: I am at the point where I'd like to implement an AOP layer on top of the framework. Read at the source code of `Go` to get inspired and understand how you weave classes.
As I understood, you modify the source code through stream filters, though I noticed that while debugging the `demo` code of your repo (e.g. `Demo\Example\CachableDemo`) it seems like PHP loads both the original `CachableDemo` class as well as its proxy version (`cache/_proxies`). How does PHP includes both if they have the same name? Do you rewrite the name on the fly within the original `Demo\Example\CachableDemo`?

Comment: I guess I understood how you do it. In debug mode, you wrap the contents of the required file with a stream filter which adds a `AOP_PROXIED_SUFFIX` suffix on the fly to the class being woven. In production mode, you just include the compiled class with the `AOP_PROXIED_SUFFIX` suffix from the cache (for performance reasons).

Comment: @tonix You could check my detailed comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47732960/801258. But in general you are right about processes in the framework.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I will take a look!

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to implement `cflow` and `cflowbelow` pointcuts in PHP? I can think about using `debug_backtrace()` in order to analize the stackframes at runtime, but the first thing that comes into my mind is the performance overhead of such an implementation...

Comment: @tonix Could you please move your questions/ideas to the Github, because they do not related to current question. Moreover, Go! AOP supports `cflowbelow` type pointcut.

Comment: OK, I will write it there!