# How does Go! AOP PHP and PHP Deal override a class with given annotations in the same namespace?

Tags: php, overriding, aop, interceptor, goaop

Whilst reading about design by contract, I came across  [php-deal](https://github.com/lisachenko/php-deal). Now, its demo code looks like this:

```
/** @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Demo', __DIR__);

include_once __DIR__.'/aspect_bootstrap.php';

$account = new Demo\Account();
$account->deposit(100);
echo $account->getBalance();
```

The `Demo\Account` class looks like this:

```
class Account implements AccountContract
{
    /**
     * Current balance
     *
     * @var float
     */
    protected $balance = 0.0;


    /**
     * Deposits fixed amount of money to the account
     *
     * @param float $amount
     *
     * @Contract\Verify("$amount>0 && is_numeric($amount)")
     * @Contract\Ensure("$this->balance == $__old->balance+$amount")
     */
    public function deposit($amount)
    {
        $this->balance += $amount;
    }


    /**
     * Returns current balance
     *
     * @Contract\Ensure("$__result == $this->balance")
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }
}
```

The annotations are the important part as they verify and ensure the contract within the annotations is executed.

Calling the class like this:

```
$account = new Demo\Account();
$account->deposit(100);
echo $account->getBalance();
```

works as expected. Calling the class like this however:

```
$account = new Demo\Account();
$account->deposit("1notanumber");
echo $account->getBalance();
```

Throws an exception about the contract not being enforced.

However, If I call the class like this:

```
$account = new Demo\Account();
$account->deposit("1notanumber");
echo $account->getBalance();

include_once __DIR__.'/aspect_bootstrap.php';

$account = new Demo\Account();
$account->deposit("1notanumber");
echo $account->getBalance();
```

The contract enforcing stops working. My question is, how does the `aspect_bootstrap.php` file override predefined PHP classes to allow for parsing and execution of annotations, and how would it be possible to do without invoking the entire Go AOP framework?

[Github repo for PHP-Deal with demo](https://github.com/lisachenko/php-deal)

Comment: What is the difference between your two 'not enforced' examples? As far as I can see the second one is the same, but some code is repeated.

Comment: the last example is the `$account` code duplicated. Once above, and once below the `aspect_bootstrap.php`. If the `$account` above `aspect_bootstrap.php` is removed, the contracts get enforced. But if its before, the contracts do not get enforced.

Comment: So they don't get enforced even before the `include`? In the normal case that code will already have run.

Comment: they get enforced only if the first instance is after the `include`. but not if there is an instance before the `include`. The `include` must be doing something to override the `Account` class to be able to enforce the contracts. I want to know what that is.

Comment: Sure, but why is the enforcement not even reported before the `include`? Is it a suppressed exception, or perhaps the reporting happens on a registered shutdown handler?

Comment: I'm very interested in GO! AOP. I did try to understand exactly how it works, but I don't completely understand yet. I think the creator gives a big hint in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24445026/921154